# Laravel Echo Doesn't connect to socket channel

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, socket.io, laravel-8

I want when my socket connection in opened increase some value in my welcome.blade.php.

this is my EventClass:

```
// app/Events/TestEvent.php
class TestEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
   ...
   public function broadcastOn()
   {
       return new Channel('test');
   }
}
```

this is my route :

```
// routes/web.php
Route::get('/fire', function () {
   event(new \App\Events\TestEvent());
   return 'ok';
});
```

this is Echo configuration in bootstrap.js :

```
// resources/js/bootstrap.js
...
import Echo from "laravel-echo"
window.io = require('socket.io-client');

window.Echo = new Echo({
   broadcaster: 'socket.io',
   host: window.location.hostname + ':6001' // this is laravel-echo-server host
});
```

and this is my welcome.blade.php :

```
// resources/views/welcome.blade.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Laravel</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    Echo.channel('test')
        .listen('TestEvent', e => {
            console.log(e)
        })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

but when I fire the TestEvent my welcome page console is empty.

Comment: Although this is a little late. Did you try implementing ShouldBroadcastNow interface on your event class instead. Or how did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you defined the `broadcastOn` function, you need to make sure you are actually listening to that channel name. Currently you are listening to the event class name, which is the default channel name when you don't provide the `broadcastOn` function.

So, change your JavaScript code to listen to `.test`, and make sure to include the dot in front of the name!

All is well explained here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#broadcast-name